# Problems with a python prime number generator

Tags: python

Sorry if this is obvious, but I'm quite new to python programming, why won't this program generate a list of prime numbers, most of them seem to be prime, but there are some that aren't.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print ("Prime Numbers")
Number = 2
while True:
    Test = 2
    while Test < Number:
        if Number % Test == 0:
            Number = Number + 1
        else:
            Test = Test + 1
    print (str(Number) + " is a prime number!")
    Number = Number + 1
```

Comment: If you follow [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) with your variable naming conventions people will find it easier to understand your code.  I feel like `Test` and `Number` should be classes, not instance variables.

Comment: try structuring the program a little more, do a function that returns a prime each call (add yield/return statements where needed)

Comment: Small tips - 1] the phrase `a = a + 1` can be rewritten as `a += 1`, which in addition to being cleaner, may be faster too. 2] In testing for prime numbers by brute force division checking, you only need to check for numbers `<N/2` not `<N`, but if you think about it more, you really only need to check the previous _prime numbers you've found already `<N/2`_. 3] Your inner while loop should be converted into a `for` statement, they are quite handy when you are iterating over a _fixed_ pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This template should help you find the prime numbers:

```
    if Number % Test == 0:
        Number = Number + 1
        Test = 2 # you'll need to reset Test here
    else:
```